# Starting reference to design SDIO host driver for linux

Tags: sdhc

I am planing to develop SDIO mmc Host driver for my Host IP Core. It follows standard register interface as per SD specifications. I want to know if there is any reference available in Linux for that. Is there any reference website that can have information on it

Comment: 'another [open source] driver'?

Comment: yes or any template can also work